# I'm unable to move my writing to the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to move `.intro .inner` to the middle so my writing are in the middle. Please help how I can move my content to the middle. It's just stuck on the top left and won't move with the CSS I have added.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet");

html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.intro {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 background: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-website-jebadicom-qy2sr/images/landing-screen.png);
 display:table;
 top: 0;
 background-size: cover;
}

.intro .inner {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: none;
}

.content {
 max-width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-left: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 28%;
}


/*---Media Queries---*/
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Jamshid Ebadi's Portolio</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta Charset='uft-8'>
  <link rel='shortcut icon' href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-website-jebadicom-qy2sr/images/favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-website-jebadicom-qy2sr/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-website-jebadicom-qy2sr/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-website-jebadicom-qy2sr/waypoints.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-website-jebadicom-qy2sr/jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-website-jebadicom-qy2sr/waypoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
<body>
  <section class="intro">
   <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
      <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="pulse" data-os-animation-delay="0s">
       <h1> Animate Easy</h1>
      </section>
      <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="pulse" data-os-animation-delay="1s">
       <a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
      </section>
      
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>

</body>

<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each element has a container.

For example we have this:

```css
.item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -height_size/2;
  margin-left: -width_size/2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

you must determine item size(width and height)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help. However, it didn't do anything. The text is still stuck on the top left.

Answer (score 0):

Better you  try Below Example in your code.

```css
.middle {
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   padding:50%;
            }
```

```html
<div class="middle">
<p>Text</P>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help. However, it didn't do anything. The text is still stuck on the top left.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare width of your content to center it. Try this solutions

```css
.middle{
margin-left:auto;
position: relative;
display:block;
margin-right:auto;
width:25%}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
<p>content</P>
</div>
```